# Logic Operator Evaluation in Bash

Tags: bash, echo, logical-operators

Logic expressions seem to evaluate in a backwards manner in Bash as opposed to a programming language like C.

For example, echo will return 0 upon success so I would expect:

```
echo hi || echo back4more
```

would print `hi` and then `back4more` to stdout since 0 is returned first and the second statement **needs** to be checked to determine the truth of the whole logical OR expression. However, it only prints `hi`.

Similarly, this can be seen from:

```
echo hi && echo back4more
```

Which I would expect to print `hi` and that's it since echo first returns 0 and thus 0 && (logic) would always be false, so no need to evaluate (logic). But what really happens is `hi` and `back4more` get printed.

Why is this so?

Comment: They aren't logical operators in this context, they are lists of commands: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists

Comment: @monsterma314 : `bash` itself "knows" logical operators only in the context of `[[ ... ]]` and `(( .... ))`. In your context, `||` is not an operator, but a statement separator. The second statement is executed only if the first one sets a non-zero status code.

Answer (score 2):

Success is not truth.

Zero *exit status* means success. Non-zero *exit status* means failure.

Zero arithmetic value is logically boolean false. Non-zero arithmetic value is logically boolean true.

> Why is this so?

The `||` checks for failure. Because `echo` exits with 0 exit status, it means success, the right side of `||` is not executed.